# Name of a group of languages with has "less is more" property

Tags: typology, terminology

Is there a name of a group of languages that try to remove instead of adding things? 
Examples:

- Newspeak: reduces words (e.g. bad will be ungood (prefix "un" meaning not), eliminate expression that are not "good" (more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak#Principles)
- [the Sij](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/comments/2cxs5e/the_10_word_language_sij/): according to author it has 10 word (or at least morpheme).

So in other words makes a language that (one or more):

- is less complex
- has less word
- has less tenses
- just "less" of something

I have only found term "Micro (artistic) language" in the wiki but it was deleted. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Artistic_language&oldid=942980010#Micro_languages) is the last version that mention it. I am not sure if such term is even used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These languages could be called **minimalist** conlangs. This term has been applied to languages like Toki Pona quite regularly, as a Google search will bear out. The term has also been used to describe a number of languages on the CBB, such as Sint and Nomadic.

The same word can be applied to parts of a language, e.g. Davush on CBB refers to their Shiruitoan language as having a minimalist phonology.